# Email template at server rather than Client level

Tags: html-email, email-templates

I use bluehost server hosting and have multiple email addresses set up on there for multiple people who all access their emails via different clients. We wanted to have a common email template with an image watermarked across.

The only way I could think of doing this would be to configure ever email client everybody uses to use this template individually. Is there an easier way one could, for example, set the server to use a particular template for all emails being sent from a particular domain or something like that?